# How can I make the font-awesome can take the full area of its parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-awesome

As you can see the thumbs are over its parent area.
The UI layout is not acceptable.

[image: inline]

The following is the expected result.
I tried to put margin-bottom with a negative number,
Or tried to make them in FLEX layout.
None of them works.
Any ideas?

[image: inline]

## Parent container

```
#vote-buttons-section .iconic-button#upvote {
  background: #7f7f7f !important;
  width: 75px;
  height: 55px; }
#vote-buttons-section .iconic-button#downvote {
  background: #7f7f7f;
  height: 55px;
  width: 75px; }
```

## Font-awesome icons appear on the BEFORE attribute

```
.ui-button.iconic-button.iconic-button-upvote:before,
.ui-button.iconic-button.iconic-button-upvote.ui-state-hover:before,
.ui-button.iconic-button.iconic-button-upvote.ui-state-focus:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f087";
  font-size: 55px;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 55px;
  }

.ui-button.iconic-button.iconic-button-downvote:before,
.ui-button.iconic-button.iconic-button-downvote.ui-state-hover:before,
.ui-button.iconic-button.iconic-button-downvote.ui-state-focus:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f088";
  font-size: 64px;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: Can you create an MCVE instead of linking to an external site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the heights of the containers are `55px`. What you can do is to add the rule `line-height: 55px;` to the part that's handling the icons. It seems like you should add it to the selectors

```
.ui-button.iconic-button.iconic-button-upvote:before,
.ui-button.iconic-button.iconic-button-upvote.ui-state-hover:before,
.ui-button.iconic-button.iconic-button-upvote.ui-state-focus:before
```

Then it should be centered. You can adjust the `font-size` if you want, as long as the `line-height` is correct, it will be centered.

Comment: Wow, you definitely solved my problem. I was trying to adjust the layout by changing font-size or container height, but none of them works. you saved me. thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! @newBike

Comment: @newBike Don't forget to accept my answer by the way

Comment: Hi, any keyword for this css knowledge?

Comment: As long as your text is one line it will be centered with this method @newBike

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is to add the `height: inherit;` and some `padding` like this:

```
#vote-buttons-section .iconic-button#upvote {
   height: inherit;
   padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

If it doesn't work, add the `!important` to the CSS properties, like this:

```
#vote-buttons-section .iconic-button#upvote {
   height: inherit !important;
   padding: 10px 10px !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** I didn't see that you solved the problem by a user that gave the answer before me. I'm glad that you fixed your issue with user **Gustaf Gunér**.